# How to cut a string in python until a certain word and from the word to the end

Tags: python-3.x, string

so basically I'm trying to cut a string from the start to a certain word and from the end of the word to the end and then add a new word in between so like:

I am a boy in a park.

'I am a'  and  'in a park'

and then enter a new word:

I am a *girl* in a park.

And I cant use like .split or find stuff. This is what I got so far.

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence:")
print(sentence)

word = input("Enter a word:")
print(word)
>! 
>! count = 0
>! num_found = 0
>! 
>! word_2 = word[1:]
>! print(word_2)
>! 
>! for i in range(len(sentence) - len(word_2)):
>! print(i, sentence[i])
>! 
>! if sentence[i] == word[0]:
>! for j in range(len(word)):
>! if sentence[i + j] == word[j]:
>! count+=1
>! if count == 3:
>! num_found+=1
>! else:
>! count = 0
>! break
>! 
>! if count == len(word):
>! print("           ", count, ":", word)
>! count = 0
>! 
>! print("Number of findings of the word:" , num_found)

replacement_word = input("Enter another word:")

first_cut = sentence[0: ?]
print(first_cut)

second_cut = sentence[  ?:]
print(second_cut)

print(first_cut + replacement_word + second_cut)
```

obviously the first_cut and second_cut part is wrong and i would like help please..? I'm just missing two variables.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can specify a delimiter when using the split method

```
text = "I am a boy in a park."

split_result = text.split("boy")

final_result = "girl".join(split_result)
```

If you can't use the split method, but you can use the replace method, this should work fine

```
txt = "I am a boy in a park."

replacement = txt.replace("boy", "girl")
```

Comment: yes but i can't use .split like i wrote before the text box code thing